# Specifying seq<int> as return type in F#

Tags: f#

I want to make a function that takes a string and returns a sequence of numbers. It should return a sequence containing only 0 if it passed a empty string. I tried doing the following:

```
let mapToInt (s: string) :seq<int> = 
    if s.Length = 0 then
        seq {0} 
    else
        s.Split ' ' 
        |> Seq.map int
```

This however gives the following error message:

```
This expression should have type 'unit', but has type 'int'. Use 'ignore' to discard the result of the expression, or 'let' to bind the result to a name.
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sequence expression needs to use `yield` to yield a value:

```
if s.Length = 0 then
    seq { yield 0 }
```

Comment: But, I would probably just `upcast [|0|]` to return an array cast to a sequence, rather than creating a generator just to return zero.